# automatic update contents in a phpmyadmin table

Tags: php

I have a PHP web site. In this all my users have an expiry date about 1 month ( if a user register today his expiry date will be 2nd of the next year).I need to automatically update the expiration date  of my user's profile and send a mail to that users( even he is logged or not). But I don't know how this? I heard about the clone function (I am not sure is it clone or not) to implement this type of automatic function. If does anyone know this please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of clone I think you mean [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).  You can set up a cron to run a php script that will do these updates for you.  Just write the php script that will do the update.  Then, in your unix shell:

```
crontab -e
```

Specify the minute/hour/dom/moy/dow that the cron should run and then `php /path/to/update/script.php`